How can export all part of columns to pdf file with VBA code?
Please download the sample.xlsx from my dropbox.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dm7okj2j5l2onlq2lmd6m/sample.xlsx?rlkey=obm03i1ysexnajay1zzv2jddy&st=tan1kkj1&dl=0
It contains simple data.

I want to export all columns in the sample.xlsx into sample.xlsx with VBA code:
Sub pdf()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim saveLocation As String
    templePath = "d:\sample.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(templePath)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    With ws.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End With
    saveLocation = "d:\sample.pdf"
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing 
End Sub

The setting .Orientation = xlLandscape can't make all columns saved in sample.pdf.

How can export all part of columns to pdf file with VBA code?



Which line gives the 1004 error ? Single step through code with F8. Note taller's code works for me.

Check you have permission to write to D:\ 

No permission to write.

Your script is almost complete; the only thing left is to reset the worksheet's print area settings.
Please check the print area in Page Break Preview mode.

Sub pdf()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim saveLocation As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim templePath As String: templePath = "d:\sample.xlsx"
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(templePath)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ws.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = "" ' reset print area setting
        .FitToPagesWide = 1 ' fit all columns to a page
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    saveLocation = "d:\sample.pdf"
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Run-time error-1004!Have you tried your VBA code?

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation

The line above when press F8,it come accross 1004 error.

No permission to write into d:.

Yes, I’ve tested the code. Regarding the error No permission to write into d:, please verify the user’s Windows settings. The user must have write permissions for the folder.

solved ,thanks.
